# Access all files in folder from FileActivated file

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-10, win-universal-app

I write a Windows 10 Universal App like the default Photo App in C#. The Photo App allows to show all images in the directory where the user opened the file with the Photo App. But when the user opened a file with my App I get only the FileActivatedEventArgs with allows to display the file the user opened. I found no solution to show the user the other files from the directory of this file too. I think the problem is to get the permission to access that files because when the folder of the file is in the picture library it works. But the Windows Photo App can this everywhere so I think there must be a solution ...

Edit: I have tried to extract a very simple sample code from my project that show the relevant part in only a few lines of code

```
public static async Task<BitmapImage> LoadImage(StorageFile file)
{
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    FileRandomAccessStream stream = (FileRandomAccessStream)await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
    return bitmapImage;
}

private async void setImages(FileActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    StorageFile si = (StorageFile)App.args.Files.First();
    StorageFolder st = await si.GetParentAsync();
    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(st);
    IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> sflist = await st.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (StorageFile sf in sflist)
    {
        imageList.Add(await LoadImage(sf));
    }
}
```

Comment: What code have you tried to display the additional images?

Comment: I have added a code sample it works in the picture library with the picture library permission for the App but on other places it fails probably because the App need the permission to access this files ... but I do not know how I can get this permission ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have NO access rights for the folder. In this case, GetParentAsync() may fall.
You should use "IFileActivatedEventArgsWithNeighboringFiles" to parse the neighboring files. By using this interface, OS's File Broker process passed the neighboring files to you.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.ifileactivatedeventargswithneighboringfiles

Note - This API was added from Win8.1. And, Win8.0 ver of Photo app can't show the neighboring files when it was activated by FileActivated. Win8.1 ver of Photo app may use this API.

Comment: Thanks args.NeighboringFilesQuery.GetFilesAsync() works perfect. I don't know why i did not find that easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following to the Package.appxmanifest file so you can access the Pictures Library then you should be able to get this to work:

```
<Capabilities> 
   <uap:Capability Name="picturesLibrary"/> 
</Capabilities>
```

Comment: I have this in my Package.appxmanifest file and yes it works in the Picture Library but if the user opens a photo outside the Picture Library for example on Desktop or on a second HDD it does not work ... I need a solution working everywhere (The Windows Photo App works everywhere so it must be possible)

Comment: Ok, then that is strange indeed it should be possible to do this, even with FileOpenPicker have done this myself when was testing for this article I wrote - http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week02jul15/preparing-your-windows-8-1-universal-apps-for-windows-10/

Comment: If my App is opened over a file I can get this file but I will get all Files in the folder (like the Windows Photo App) so the user can click in the App to switch to the next photo. It works in the picture library and on a removable storage media it works too because then I can add the removableStorage permission for that. But for the Desktop or a second HDD I can not find a permission to solve this problem ... and picture on the second disk is a common use case because many users have a ssd with limited storage space as the first disk …

Comment: Indeed it does seem like that should work, is something I'd wanted to work on myself so am keen to see an answer to this too now I realise the issue here