# How can I browse through the neighboring files in my Windows 10 App?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, filesystems

I try to make a photo editor/viewer as the Windows 10 App. I let the user to open an image file by `FileOpenPicker`. The program also should be able to browse other images from the same folder as the selected file (e.g. by previous and next buttons), but there is the problem. I even can't get file names of these images.

All the methods I have tried just return `null`...

```
// File picker to let user select the image file - works OK
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg"); 
var file = await picker.PickSingleFileAsync();  

// These methods to get neighboring files do not work
// 1. using Directory.GetFiles - it returns empty string
string filePaths[] = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Path));
// 2. using GetParentAsync - it returns null instead of file's parent folder
var folder = await file.GetParentAsync();
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

So, how can I browse through the other files from the same folder as the already opened file?

I have found I can use a `FolderPicker` to get access to given folder, but that would be a very silly solution if the user need to go through two pickers (one for the image file and another for the actual file's folder).

EDIT: After I checked Removable Storage and Picture Library in App Manifest, the `GetParentAsync` started to work for USB drives, but when I open an image file from any local drive it still returns null. Why it does not work for local HDD drives, which are the logical storage device for large amount of photos? Storing data only to user folders on small SSD system drive or USB drive is so limiting.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, If user pick a 'File' by FilePicker, you have the rights only for the 'File'. Not for parent folder. (If you have access rights for picture library and the file is located at the library, you can access the folder. But, the rights comes from library access, not from the file.)

This is a design of WinRT's file accessing rule via FileBroker.. It's hard to overcome.

My recommendation (and many of storeapp picture viewer choose this way, including my app PICT8) is, Ask user to set the folder that the user mainly used to keep the image files by using FolderPicker.
You can keep the access rights for the folder by using FAL or MRU. Instead of using FilePicker, You can show the list of files to your user.

[StorageApplicationPermissions class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.aspx)

And...My answer for another thread may help you also: [Access all files in folder from FileActivated file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31741615/access-all-files-in-folder-from-fileactivated-file/31782309)

Answer (score 0):

You got a `StorageFile` from the `FileOpenPicker`. You can get the containing folder with the `GetParentAsync` method and then call `GetFilesAsync` to get the files inside the folder.

```
var folder = await file.GetParentAsync();
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
var next = files.SkipWhile(x => x.Name == file.Name)
                .Skip(1)
                .First();
```

As you can see you can get the next file inside the folder be skipping ech file until you find your current. Then skip it and take the first after your file.

I think it would better to order the files before you acccess them by calling `OrderBy` respectivly `OrderByDescending` on the `files` result.
You are able to pass a lambda expression to select an property or value for sorting.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I have a major problem even with GetParentAsync(), which returns null in most cases. Actually it works only for my USB drive, but not for any other location (e.g. when I open a file from local drive D: where I store all my photos). So, I need to make GetParentAsync working for all cases.

Comment: @MichalDvorak I cannot test it yet but make sure that you enabled all neccessary permissions inside the app manifest

Comment: I checked the capabilities in app manifest, but all I can enable is Picture Library and Removable Storage. It seems there is no way to make GetParentAsync() working for local drives. Which is huge shame, because I think many users (including me) store their photos on a large HDD and not in any windows picture folder on small SSD, which is dedicated only to system and programs.